# Functions( api call) returns an Empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make an api call , check the data to make sure it's there but for some reason my array that it return is empty.

```js
export const fetchFiveDayWeather = (lat, lon) => {
  axios.get(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
 lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&APPID=${apiKey}&units=metric`
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      return response.data
    });
}
```

Code of the function:

[image]

Comment: Are you getting data in then block. means can you see the response data in console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `fetchFiveDayWeather` with `then` like below.
Because the then returns a promise and it's an async call.

```
fetchFiveDayWeather().then( response => {
   console.log(response );
})
```